# Copying std::vector between threads without locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

I have a vector that is modified in one thread, and I need to use its contents in another. Locking between these threads is unacceptable due to performance requirements. Since iterating over the vector while it is changing will cause a crash, I thought to copy the vector and then iterate over the copy. My question is, can this way also crash?

```
struct Data
{
    int A;
    double B;
    bool C;
};

std::vector<Data> DataVec;

void ModifyThreadFunc()
{
    // Here the vector is changed, which includes adding and erasing elements
    ...
}

void ReadThreadFunc()
{
    auto temp = DataVec;    // Will this crash?
    for (auto& data : temp)
    {
        // Do stuff with the data
        ...
    }

    // This definitely can crash
    /*for (auto& data : DataVec)
    {
        // Do stuff with the data
        ...
    }*/
}
```

The basic thread safety guarantee for `vector::operator=` is:

> "if an exception is thrown, the container is in a valid state."

What types of exceptions are possible here?

**EDIT:**

I solved this using double buffering, and posted my answer below.

Comment: You know that copying is iterating over the vector, right? It's still the same problem.

Comment: Without protection you can modify the vector while reading it at the same time, leading to *undefined behavior*. And one possibility of UB is to crash. Or to seemingly work okay. Or summon [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: `auto temp = DataVec;` is not atomic, you have to avoid one thread modifying while the other executes the `operator=`

Comment: @StoryTeller I was not sure about this, I sort of expected the implementation to be along the lines of memcpy

Comment: @tobi303 I cannot avoid the modification, and can't lock it with a mutex

Comment: I imagine your data is not just a structure of three fundamental types. It has to call destructors and constructors for anything that isn't POD.

Comment: Copying is Iterating. In simple case you get data that doesnt fit to each other (f.e. your vector blinks with ('A','B','C' ...'Z' and 'a', 'b', 'c' .. 'z' and you get 'A','b','C', .. 'z'). But what, if length changes? At the beginning of of your loop it still has the item number 3, but when you want to copy you copy from invalid.

Comment: @StoryTeller My struct is just POD. Pretty much what I wrote there, with an additional unsigned long long

Comment: Why do you deem that "locking is unacceptable due to performance requirements"?   Have you conducted measurements and found that performance is unacceptable with locking, and acceptable (even if wrong) without locking?    Or are you just guessing?

Comment: `Locking between these threads is unacceptable due to performance requirements.` you don't even know what is the cost and anyway, you haven't considered more sane approaches like RWlock

Comment: @DavidHaim I have experience multithreading with mutexes, and in this particular case locking is problematic. I specifically asked for an answer without locking, and not for someone to assume that I don't know what I'm talking about

Comment: The fact you're seeking concurrent reads and writes without any form of synchronisation strongly suggests you don't know what you're talking about. The point is preventing a writer thread or a reader thread from preempting the other while it is partway through an operation.   Unless you can ensure they never overlap in time (e.g. guarantee the writer thread finishes before the reader thread starts) then locking, in some form (mutex, condition variable, critical section, atomics) is required. You could use message passing but that only means the operating system handles locking, not you.

Comment: @EyalK. @Peter : `Unless you can ensure they never overlap in time` - even that doesn't ensure that that a writing on one core will be visible on another. locking or atomic operations is a must.

Comment: @David Haim - The issue is not actually between cores - it is between caches.   There are techniques (e.g. a memory fence to force cache coherency) to guarantee that the reader reads what was written - but use of that relies on not subsequently trying to do reads and writes concurrently (i.e. separation in time).   I suppose it's a philosophical question whether that is still considered a lock though.

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out by the other answers, what you ask for is not doable. If you have concurrent access, you need synchronization, end of story.

That being said, it is not unusual to have requirements like yours where synchronization is not an option. In that case, what you can still do is *get rid of the concurrent access*. For example, you mentioned that the data is accessed once per frame in a game-loop like execution. Is it strictly required that you get the data from the current frame or could it also be the data from the *last* frame?

In that case, you could work with *two* vectors, one that is being written to by the producer thread and one that is being read by all the consumer threads. At the end of the frame, you simply swap the two vectors. Now you no longer need *(*1)* fine-grained synchronization for the data access, since there is no concurrent data access any more.

This is just one example how to do this. If you need to get rid of locking, start thinking about how to organize data access so that you avoid getting into the situation where you need synchronization in the first place.

*(*1)*: Strictly speaking, you still need a synchronization point that ensures that when you perform the swapping, all the writer and reader threads have finished working. But this is far easier to do (usually you have such a synchronization point at the end of each frame anyway) and has a far lesser impact on performance than synchronizing on every access to the vector.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, can this way also crash?

Yes, you still have a data race. If thread A modifies the vector while thread B is creating a copy, all iterators to the vector are invalidated.

> What types of exceptions are possible here?

`std::vector::operator=(const vector&)` will throw on memory allocation failure, or if the contained elements throw on copy. The same thing applies to copy construction, which is what the line in your code marked "*Will this crash?*" is actually doing.

---

The fundamental problem here is that `std::vector` is not thread-safe. You *have* to either protect it with a lock/mutex, or replace it with a thread-safe container (such as [the lock-free containers in Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) or [libcds](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: I can guarantee the vector size using reserve (I know the maximum size that it can get to), will I have any issues with just straight up access to the memory through vector::data()? My structs are made up of basic data types, nothing fancy.

Comment: @EyalK.: `std::vector::insert` et. al. still invalidate some iterators, even if no reallocation is made. And even if you'd only modify elements, or only `push_back`/`pop_back` elements, you will still have a data race on the contents of the vector, _and_ any reads while copying (including the inevitable read of `size()`, the value of which may change before you're done copying) are not guaranteed to be atomic anyway.

Comment: Like I said, the fundamental problem is that you are not using a thread-safe container. The solution to this problem is to either protect that container, or to use one that _is_ thread-safe.

Comment: Thread safe is slow. All I need is not to have any crashes that I can't recover from. Worst case I get the correct data on the next frame

Comment: @EyalK. *Thread safe is slow.*  Then your design with a non-thread-safe container is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @EyalK.: The only way to guarantee "not to have any crashes you can't recover from" is to not have undefined behavior caused by data races. Now, if you're willing to bet on UB being nice to you, then go ahead, but it's going to backfire.

Comment: @T.C.: The OP specifically asks what exceptions `std::vector::operator=` may throw, but you're right, the line marked "_Will this crash?_" is copy construction, not assignment. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a vector that is modified in one thread, and I need to use its contents in another. Locking between these threads is unacceptable due to performance requirements.

this is an impossible to meet requirement.

Anyway, any sharing of data between 2 threads will require a kind of locking, be it explicit or implementation (eventually hardware) provided. You must examine again your actual requirements: it can be inacceptable to suspend one thread until the other one ends, but you could lock short sequences of instructions. And/or possibly use a diffent architecture. For example erasing an item in a vector is a costly operation (linear time because you have to move all the data above the removed item) while marking it as invalid is much quicker (constant time because it is one single write). If you really have to erase in the middle of a vector, maybe a list would be more appropriate.

But if you can put a locking exclusion around the copy of the vector in `ReadThreadFunc` and around any vector modification in `ModifyThreadFunc`, it could be enough. To give a priority to the modifying thread, you could just try to lock in the other thread and immediately give up if you cannot.

Comment: I just need the program not to crash. It's fine if the copied vector is not 100% correct, as it will be fine in the next frame.

Comment: @EyalK. *I just need the program not to crash. It's fine if the copied vector is not 100% correct, as it will be fine in the next frame.* You can need it all you want - it's undefined behavior and even if it doesn't crash when you test it, the next run may very well crash.  And then when you upgrade your C++ runtime it might start crashing every time.

Comment: @EyalK.: then you need to set up and use some sort of synchronization...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rethink your design!

Each thread should have his own vector (list, queue whatever fit your needs) to work on. So thread A can do some work and pass the result to thrad B. You simply have to lock when writing the data from thread A int thread B's queue.

Without some kind of locking it's not possible.

Answer (score -3):

So I solved this using double buffering, which guarantees no crashing, and the reading thread will always have usable data, even if it might not be correct:

```
struct Data
{
    int A;
    double B;
    bool C;
};

const int MAXSIZE = 100;
Data Buffer[MAXSIZE];
std::vector<Data> DataVec;

void ModifyThreadFunc()
{
    // Here the vector is changed, which includes adding and erasing elements
    ...

    // Copy from the vector to the buffer
    size_t numElements = DataVec.size();
    memcpy(Buffer, DataVec.data(), sizeof(Data) * numElements);
    memset(&Buffer[numElements],  0, sizeof(Data) * (MAXSIZE - numElements));
}

void ReadThreadFunc()
{
    Data* p = Buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
    {
        // Use the data
        ...
        ++p;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still has the problem that `Buffer`, in your code, may still be accessed concurrently by two threads.    You're just getting lucky in your testing.

Comment: @Peter I have no problem that it is accessed by 2 threads, since it always exists, it can't crash. As I said, worst case the contents are wrong when it is read, but that only lasts for one frame, and it can't bring my program down. Just like in video buffering, I can get frame tearing, but that is acceptable in this case

Comment: The `memcpy()` call is not necessarily atomic, so can be preempted by the code "use the data".   True, the result will probably not be a crash.   The potential consequence is poisoning of data that the reader thread obtains from that buffer.   The consequences of data poisoning depends on how the data is used.

Comment: @EyalK. *I have no problem that it is accessed by 2 threads, since it always exists, it can't crash.* Wrong. It **can** crash because you can access the data while it's being modified. If you expect consistent data and don't get it - a non-nul-terminated string for example - you may very well crash.  You've merely traded one race condition for another.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Since it's my program I know what it does with the data, and a crash is not possible, unlike the case of iterator invalidation. Funny that you think you know what my code does better than me

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked, and still suffers from undefined behavior due to data race.

Comment: To expand on the data "poisoning" comment by @Peter... the data being accessed by multiple threads includes type `double` which is probably IEEE 754(?).  If the reader accesses a `double` part way through its modification what's to say it won't end up with a `double` whose bit pattern corresponds to a signaling nan?  If that's then used without first being tested then very bad things can still happen.

Comment: double means double. If a solution like this had to be written, it would imply 2 vectors (pointers). But again you would need some atomic stuff to exchange which is written and which is read, with some hope that all that had to be read was effectively so. Or both threads could be synchronized with a same start (this is like video as you mentioned it). Again with some hope that CPU load is not too high and that all operations achieved in/on time